# TextBox Column In DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have added `TextBox` control inside the grid: I want my `DataGridView` `TextBox` column to hold numbers without any decimal values. How can I do it?

Comment: you will need to subscribe to the textchanged event of the textbox and disallow the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/919b059c-dba9-40d2-bac7-608a9b120336

> You can handle the DataGridView.EditingControlShowing event to cast
>   the editing control to TextBox when editing in the column you want to
>   restrict input on, and attach KeyPress event to the TextBox, in the
>   KeyPress event handler function, we can call the char.IsNumber()
>   method to restrict the key board input, something like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   dt.Columns.Add("c1", typeof(int));
   dt.Columns.Add("c2");
   for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
   {
      dt.Rows.Add(j, "aaa" + j.ToString());
   }

   this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
   this.dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing +=
      new DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(
         dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing);
}

private bool IsHandleAdded;

void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender,
    DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsHandleAdded &&
       this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
   {
      TextBox tx = e.Control as TextBox;
      if (tx != null)
      {
         tx.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(tx_KeyPress);
         this.IsHandleAdded = true;
      }
   }
}

void tx_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   if (!(char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == '\b'))
   {
      e.Handled = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: I think the `IsHandleAdded` variable in this case will only allow 1 row to be edited.  Once one row is edited, then you set it to `true` and all subsequent rows wont hook up the tx_KeyPress event.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing;
}

private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender , DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
   // Convert the editing control to a TextBox to register for KeyPress event
   TextBox txt_edit = e.Control as TextBox;
   if(txt_edit != null)
   {
      // Remove any existing handler
      txt_edit.KeyPress -= TextBoxKeyPressed;
      // Add the new handler
      txt_edit.KeyPress += TextBoxKeyPressed;
   }
}

private void TextBoxKeyPressed(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   // Test for numeric value or backspace in first column
   // Change this to whatever column you only want digits for
   if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
   {
      // If its a numeric or backspace, display it.  Not a numeric, ignore it
      e.Handled = (!Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text)
```